# jQuery remove HTML elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

Here are 4 list items

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

I want to update the items from server so I write AJAX call.

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    $('ul').append('new 4 items from server');
});
```

Items after AJAX call

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
    <li>new1</li>
    <li>new2</li>
    <li>new3</li>
    <li>new4</li>
</ul>
```

So total items count is 8. Now I want to keep last 5 items `Fourth, new1...new4` and remove remaining. How can I do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: I have no idea on DOWN VOTE, please comment how can I improve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:lt(index)` selector.

```
$('ul li:lt(3)').remove();
```

If you only want to keep the five last `li` elements you can use `eq` and `prevAll` methods:

```
$('ul li').eq(-5).prevAll().remove();
```

Or before appending new elements remove all the list elements except the last one.